# drawRect doesn't draw rect - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d

I just want to draw a rect on a view. This is my code in my UIView subclass:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 1);
CGContextAddRect(context, (CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)));

}
```

When I run it no rect is drawn. What's wrong?

Comment: Because it is not acually drawn :)

Comment: Please read the docs for the functions you are using :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGContextAddRect` just adds a rectangular path to the context. You need to stroke or fill the path as well using `CGContextFillPath` or `CGContextStrokePath`.

You can also fill a rect directly with `UIRectFill` or `CGContextFillRect`.